# List all mocha tests without executing them

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

Is there a way in mochajs to list all tests collected by test runner without executing them?

E.g. if there are specs that look like:

```
describe('First', function() {
    it('should test something', function() {
        ...
    })
});

describe('Second', function() {
    it('should test something else', function() {
        ...
    })
});
```

then I want to get console output similar to an output produced by test reporters, but without executing actual tests, like this:

```
First
    should test something
Second
    should test something else
```

**UPD:**

Currently I'm extracting all `describe`s and `it`s with regex, but looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of `mocha@9`, the [dry-run option](https://mochajs.org/#-dry-run%60) ([PR here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/pull/4640)) has been added.

If you want to list (and programmatically make use of) all tests, you want to enable `dry-run` and probably the `json` reporter + an output filepath like so:

```json
{
  "dry-run": true,
  "reporter": "json",
  "reporterOptions": [
    "output": "./test-report.json"
  ]
}
```

## How to produce a test list that we can use programmatically?

If you want to use the test output programmatically:

As of [this commit](https://github.com/dorny/mocha/commit/6a93d47baa9b256a4ce57c6d034e7ec04b75f58c#diff-2ffde0cb419cc8885c51d968ef0bb9ec9c69350e766d45b98277405f35041c7eR81) (Aug 2021), you can just provide the `output` file config option, and then read the json file from your test processing program.

<s>tough luck.
Turns out, the JSON reporter, contrary to its name, does not produce pure JSON (as discussed [in this outstanding Mocha issue](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/4131)).
As a workaround, I wrote a little script ([gist here](https://gist.github.com/Domiii/ff89e1427ee51193721abdbb08842e58)), that works like so:</s>

1. Store mocha output to file: `npm run test > tests-raw.json`

   - Or: `yarn test > tests-raw.json`
   - Or: `mocha --dry-run --reporter=json ... > tests-raw.json`
2. Convert the output: `./mocha-list-tests.js tests-raw.json tests.json`
3. The file `tests.json` now contains an array of all the test result objects. Each call to `mocha` that was recorded should yield one such object.

### More Config Options

I could not find much documentation on the exact output format, but it's mostly just two things:

- `stats` - basic overall stats
- `tests` - all found tests (see [Test#serialize method](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/34643e4c0821aeb8d6977c1942bc106c9363789a/lib/test.js#L92))
- `failures`, `pending`, `passes`

Answer (score 6):

The mocha-list-tests package is useful, but only works for BDD style `describe()` and `it()`, and it breaks if you `.skip()` any tests because it mocks `it()`.

One way to do this yourself if you need to overcome either of those things, or get other information on the tests, is to exploit Mocha's root `before()` hook.  This will be executed after Mocha has loaded all files but before it executes any tests, so all the information you need exists at that point.

This way, it is pretty easy to patch in a `--list-only` command line option to switch the behaviour of your test run without having to add or change anything else.

The key is that `this` in the `before()` hook is Mocha's `Context`, and the `.test` of that refers to the hook itself.  So `this.test.parent` refers to the root suite.  From there, you can walk down the tree of `.suites` arrays, and `.tests` arrays of each suite.

Having collected whatever you want, you have to then output that and exit the process to stop Mocha from continuing.

### Plain Text Example

Given **root.js**:

```
#!/bin/env mocha

before(function() {
    if(process.argv.includes('--list-only')) {
        inspectSuite(this.test.parent, 0);
        process.exit(0);
    }
    // else let Mocha carry on as normal...
});

function inspectSuite(suite, depth) {
    console.log(indent(`Suite ${suite.title || '(root)'}`, depth));

    suite.suites.forEach(suite => inspectSuite(suite, depth +1));
    suite.tests.forEach(test => inspectTest(test, depth +1));
}

function inspectTest(test, depth) {
    console.log(indent(`Test ${test.title}`, depth));
}

function indent(text, by) {
    return '    '.repeat(by) + text;
}
```

And **test.js**:

```
#!/bin/env mocha

describe('foo', function() {
    describe('bar', function() {
        it('should do something', function() {
            // ...
        });
    });

    describe('baz', function() {
        it.skip('should do something else', function() {
            // ...
        });

        it('should do another thing', function() {
            // ...
        });
    });
});
```

Then running `mocha` as normal would give you the test results you expect:

```
  foo
    bar
      ✓ should do something
    baz
      - should do something else
      ✓ should do another thing


  2 passing (8ms)
  1 pending
```

But running `mocha --list-only` would give you (without running any tests):

```
Suite (root)
    Suite foo
        Suite bar
            Test should do something
        Suite baz
            Test should do something else
            Test should do another thing
```

### JSON Example

**root.js**

```
#!/bin/env mocha

before(function() {
    let suites = 0;
    let tests = 0;
    let pending = 0;

    let root = mapSuite(this.test.parent);

    process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify({suites, tests, pending, root}, null, '    '));
    process.exit(0);

    function mapSuite(suite) {
        suites += +!suite.root;
        return {
            title: suite.root ? '(root)' : suite.title,
            suites: suite.suites.map(mapSuite),
            tests: suite.tests.map(mapTest)
        };
    }

    function mapTest(test) {
        ++tests;
        pending += +test.pending;
        return {
            title: test.title,
            pending: test.pending
        };
    }
});
```

With the same test script as before would give you:

```
{
    "suites": 3,
    "tests": 3,
    "pending": 1,
    "root": {
        "title": "(root)",
        "suites": [
            {
                "title": "foo",
                "suites": [
                    {
                        "title": "bar",
                        "suites": [],
                        "tests": [
                            {
                                "title": "should do something",
                                "pending": false
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "baz",
                        "suites": [],
                        "tests": [
                            {
                                "title": "should do something else",
                                "pending": true
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "should do another thing",
                                "pending": false
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "tests": []
            }
        ],
        "tests": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap all your describe blocks in a describe block and **skip** it.

```
describe.skip('Outline', function() {
    describe('First', function() {
        it('should test something', function() {
            ...
        })
    });

    describe('Second', function() {
        it('should test something else', function() {
            ...
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: While this prints out a list of tests, it doesn't really solve the problem. I don't see how I can use this solution for a project where tests are stored in multiple files and list of tests needs to be retrieved periodically.

Comment: What you really want is `--dry-run` option which had already been proposed but never get merged. See [mocha pull request #1070](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/pull/1070)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for, sad it wasn't accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**`mocha-list-tests` package**

I kid you not, there is a separate package for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-list-tests

```
npm install mocha mocha-list-tests
node ./node_modules/mocha-list-tests/mocha-list-tests.js main.js
```

Sample output:

```
{
  "suites": [
    "a1",
    "a2"
  ],
  "tests": [
    "a1.a11",
    "a1.a12",
    "a2.a21",
    "a2.a22"
  ],
  "tree": {
    "a1": {
      "a11": true,
      "a12": true
    },
    "a2": {
      "a21": true,
      "a22": true
    }
  }
}
```

for this test file:

main.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const assert = require('assert');
const fs = require('fs');

describe('a1', function() {
  it('a11', function() {
    assert.equal(1, 1);
    fs.writeFileSync('abc', 'def', 'utf8');
  });
  it('a12', function() {
    assert.equal(1, 2);
  });
});
describe('a2', function() {
  it('a21', function() {
    assert.equal(1, 1);
  });
  it('a22', function() {
    assert.equal(1, 2);
  });
});
```

The file `abc` was not created, so I know that tests were not executed.

This is likely using the API Mocha mentioned at: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-Mocha-programmatically

Teste in mocha@6.2.2, mocha-list-tests@1.0.2, Node v10.15.1.

Comment: For info, no, it doesn't use the API.  It specifically mocks `describe()` and `it()` and then `require()`s the test script, capturing the usage of those.

Comment: Did not work. Luckily, [mocha-decaf](https://github.com/sh3raawii/mocha-decaf) did work.

Comment: @Domi same veresions of mocha and mocha-list-tests? What's the output?

Comment: `mocha-list-tests` did not output anything, just produced an empty object. Luckily its not necessary anymore since `mocha` finally added the `dry-run` option - see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68829700/2228771).

Comment: (FYI: I tested it on the `sequelize` `test` folder, with `DIALECT=sqlite`)